# www redirect with double slash

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, no-www

When I enter my website http://domain.com it redirects to http://www.domain.com// (double slash in the end).

What is strange, I haven't set any redirects in .htaccess file. Actually that file  is empty. I've tried to add some rewrite rules there, but the same problem appeared again.

I can't understand where have been set that non-www to www redirect? Do you have any ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: whats your default.php (or other default file? is any code in it?)

Comment: There is no any default file(I've removed index.php). And even now with fully empty website redirect still appears. (When all the files are removed it is opening apache test page).

Comment: This is probably something you host does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this code to remove double slashes from the urls.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^ $0 [R=302]
```

Change the 302 to 301 once you get it working.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped! One more question. Is it possible to combine that code with this one 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(?:|/(.*))?$ index.php?request_path=$0  [QSA,NE]`

Thanks

Comment: Just put these (my) lines above your other rules, and you'll be fine.