# Redirect if someone add / to the url

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

i just wanted to know that how to remove more than one / from url from htaccess forex:-

This is the original url

```
http://example.com/folder/page.php
```

What if someone add another slash to folder like this

```
http://example.com/folder//page.php
```

It still showing page content but without any css and script. And how to prevent from adding /\ and redirect to the original url.

I am seeing this in most of the websites they redirect but my website is not redirecting.

I don't know it's a server issue or programmers issue. I contacted my hosting manager they are saying it's a programmers issue.

Can you please help me out with this

How to prevent from this and redirect using htaccess

Comment: Is it resolving your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122817/www-redirect-with-double-slash

Comment: Thanks for the helping actually i just came to know that htaccess file also not working. I am trying to make it work then try this solution. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [www redirect with double slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122817/www-redirect-with-double-slash)

Comment: No, i have copy and pasted the code and put it on the top but this did not work and the url is tried for this is like this [http://example.com//]